# declaring consts inside if parathesis in js/ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

In PHP I can declare variables inside if statement parenthesis:

```php
if ($myvar = myfunction()) {
  // do things with $myvar
}
```

Is anything similar possible in JS / TS?:

```js
if (const myvar = myfunction()) {
    // do things with myvar
}
```

Comment: Declarations like `const` are [not statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#difference_between_statements_and_declarations) nor expressions, so no, you can't do this.

Comment: For if block there is no possible way to scope the variable to the if block.

Comment: There's [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Declarations-in-Conditionals) to add this feature to the language, but currently it is not supported

Comment: `{ const myvar = myfunction(); if (myvar) { … } }` or `for (const myvar = myfunction(); myvar;) { …; break; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that in JavaScript.

You need to declare your const outside ghe if statement:

```
const myvar = myfunction();

if (myvar) {
  // Do something with myvar
}
```